# Customize MSBuild targets for the OpenApiReference element

Tags: rest, .net-core, msbuild

I would like to customize the OpenApiReference element targets. Specifically, I would like to run a custom target just before the targets defined by the OpenApiReference element. How can I do that?

Assume the following configuration:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Namespace="IntegrationService">
      <Options>/GenerateDtoTypes:false /GenerateClientInterfaces:true</Options>
      <ClassName>IntegrationServiceClient</ClassName>
    </OpenApiReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reviewing the MS source code I was able to solve the requirement as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OpenApiGenerateCodeOnBuild>false</OpenApiGenerateCodeOnBuild>
    <OpenApiGenerateCodeAtDesignTime>false</OpenApiGenerateCodeAtDesignTime>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="openapi.json" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Namespace="IntegrationService">
      <Options>/GenerateDtoTypes:false /GenerateClientInterfaces:true</Options>
      <ClassName>IntegrationServiceClient</ClassName>
    </OpenApiReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="DeleteServiceClient" >
    <Message Text="------ Custom target: Removing existing generated service client for $(ProjectName)" Importance="high"/>
    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)/openapiClient.cs" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="GenerateServiceClient" DependsOnTargets="DeleteServiceClient;GenerateOpenApiCode" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile"/>
</Project>
```

References:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.10/src/Tools/Extensions.ApiDescription.Client/src/build/Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client.targets
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.10/src/Tools/Extensions.ApiDescription.Client/src/build/Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client.props
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.10/src/Tools/Extensions.ApiDescription.Client/src/buildMultiTargeting/Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client.targets